# How to run a pipeline on new PRs only if files in a certain directory are changed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a repository with 2 directories, one with python code and one with C code.
I want to run one pipeline on all PRs only when the files in the python folder (hello_app) change.
I have used the following yaml file but the pipeline still runs when a new PR contains changes (only) outside of the hello_app directory:

```
trigger:
- none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    exclude:
    - '*'
    include:
    - hello_app/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python27:
      python.version: '2.7'
    Python36:
      python.version: '3.6'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    python -m pip install flake8
    flake8 .
  displayName: 'Run linter tests'

- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pytest
  displayName: 'pytest'
```

I tried to search online, but seems like this should work. Is there something wrong with the yaml I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#pr-trigger):

> YAML PR triggers are supported only in GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud. If
> you use Azure Repos Git, you can configure a branch policy for build
> validation to trigger your build pipeline for validation.

If your are using the Azure Repo, you need to configure a branch policy for build validation to trigger your build pipeline for validation.

You could navigate to `branch policy -> build validation`  and set the path filter(`/hello_app/*`).

Here is my example:

[image]

Then it could work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Azure Repo and this worked. just that I had to add a '/' at the start of the path for this work, i.e., `/hello_app/*` worked.